# Creating a constructor function with multiple enum states for a card game?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, constructor, enums

I am trying to code a custom object where I want multiple letters associated or tagged to it.

I'm trying to code a similar setup where an Object can have multiple letters (or booelan flags) assigned to it.

For example, `Company` might have the letters "A,B,C,F" (out of letters A through F).

I'd like to create an `Company` card and assign it certain letters in a constructor method.

At first I thought I'd use an array -- but I'd like to keep the letters seperate as the letters are really just a big matrix of "boolean" flags.

```
IE:
Letters          A    B   C   D   E   F
"Brand X"        Y    Y   N   N   Y   N
```

My code as follows;

```
typedef enum _Letters {
    LetterA,
    LetterB,
    LetterC,
    LetterD,
    LetterE,
    LetterF,
} Letters;

@interface Corporation : NSObject
{
    NSString *_name; // Name of the card ie: "Automative"
    NSArray *_letters; // A->F
    int _value; // Value of the card in $
    VENCardState _state; // Current state of the card (is it in play or discard pile, etc)
}
```

What I'd like but am sure about is how to make `letters` contain all the letters I want in an init constructor function.

ie;

`initWithLetters:A,B,C....`

But am unsure of how to do this.

Basically I want a simple way of making a constructor that will have multiple enum states and then the method will add these enum states into an array of `letters`

I should be able to log the object and discover what letters it is associated with.

Comment: what object will the `_letters` hold a complete VENLetters or a single A ?

Comment: _letters is meant to hold multiple letters. It could be 'A', but it can be 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'.  It can either be a single letter or multiple letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
- (id) initWithLetters:(VENLetters)letter, ...;
or:
- (id) initWithLettersArray:(NSArray*)lettersArray;

Comment: With the second one, initWithLettersArray looks very good. I will try this.

Comment: I get an assertion error if I try to do this: `Corporation *steel = [[Corporation alloc] initWithName:@"Steel" withValue:8 withLetters:steelLetters];
        [steel log];
        [steel release];`

Comment: My constructor looks like: `-(id) initWithName:(NSString *)name withValue:(int)value withLetters:(NSArray *)lettersArray
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = name;
        _value = value;
        _letters = [lettersArray copy];
    }
    return self;
}`

Comment: error about what? Are you write without ARC? why [steel release]?

Comment: The error is related to the steelLetters, I am currently trying to do a standard object creation rather than a constructor to see if I can identify the problem.  The reason why I am not writing without ARC is because of "habit".  I will move to ARC later on, right now its just a hacky thought experiement I thought I'd give a shot on.

Comment: I think I've identified the issue being related to LetterA, LetterB not being objects, ala: `steel.letters = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:LetterB, LetterC, nil];`

Comment: I will accept your answer @Leta0n, This has solved my problem. Thanks